# Final boolean field not initialized when object is created via Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, initialization, final

found a strange things today. 
I have a protected final boolean field:

```
 protected final boolean active = true;
```

As you can see, I expect this field to be initialized with TRUE value after object is instantiated. This is a database model class. I use mybatis 3.1.1 to read data from the database.
What I see is when I do call to db using mybatis SqlSession.selectOne() I receive an object with active == false! But I don't change this field in sql query.
I dug through mybatis code and found that in `DefaultObjectFactory.java#create(Class<T>, List<Class<?>>, List<Object>)` my object is instantiated and has this final 'active' field equal to FALSE.
well, I'm totally confused and cannot find any information regarding it.
Could someone please explain what's going on here? as I thought that final field must be initialized after constructor logic is over.

Comment: Ordinary Reflection can’t bypass the constructor, so this can’t be possible in this case. Deserialization can, but this would imply that the field was already `false` when the object was stored. Generally, there is little sense in a `final` instance field of this kind. No ordinary code will ever notice what is actually stored in the field, as this is a compile-time constant.

Comment: I looked into that `DefaultObjectFactory` and it straight-forwardly uses `java.lang.reflect.Constructor`, so it can’t bypass the initialization. The question is, how did you come to the conclusion that `active` is `false`.

Comment: @Holger, i looked into debugger.  That instantiated object is then being sent over SOAP to the client and client sees it as false too.

Comment: Make sure that the compiled class matches the source code. Then, “being sent over SOAP” by *what*? Does it read the fields or invoke getters?

Comment: @Holger, thanks. will check. Maybe intellij idea tomcat runner messed up the classes.

Comment: Gson and some other tools that fall back to `Unsafe.allocateInstance` bypass initialization, but if myBatis goes through normal reflection, this could not happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Holger!

I messed up with classes. Final field initialization works as expected.